# JQuery find Duplicate Ids in JSON Array

Tags: jquery

I have a JSON array as below:

```
[{
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "A"
}, {
    "Id": "2",
    "Name": "B"
}, {
    "Id": "3",
    "Name": "C"
}, {
    "Id": "4",
    "Name": "B"
}, {
    "Id": "5",
    "Name": "D"
}, {
    "Id": "6",
    "Name": "E"
}, {
    "Id": "7",
    "Name": "C"
}, {
    "Id": "8",
    "Name": "D"
}]
```

I want to find out ID's of duplicate name. e.g. from above array I should get an array which return the Ids of duplicate name.

2
3
4
5
7
8

As B,C,D appears more than once in the loop.

Comment: and what is the problem you' re experiencing?

Comment: Trying to get the duplicate Ids where name is not unique. Hoping to get some solution which is not slow and messy with multiple loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myArray = [{
  "Id": "1",
  "Name": "A"
}, {
  "Id": "2",
  "Name": "B"
}, {
  "Id": "3",
  "Name": "C"
}, {
  "Id": "4",
  "Name": "B"
}, {
  "Id": "5",
  "Name": "D"
}, {
  "Id": "6",
  "Name": "E"
}, {
  "Id": "7",
  "Name": "C"
}, {
  "Id": "8",
  "Name": "D"
}];

var repeat_ids=[];


for(var key1 in myArray){
   var exists_name_len = $.map(myArray, function(n, i) {if(n.Name==myArray[key1].Name){ return i; }}).length;
   if(exists_name_len>1){repeat_ids.push(myArray[key1].Id);}
}

console.log(repeat_ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array:

```
var myArray = [{
  "Id": "1",
  "Name": "A"
}, {
  "Id": "2",
  "Name": "B"
}, {
  "Id": "3",
  "Name": "C"
}, {
  "Id": "4",
  "Name": "B"
}, {
  "Id": "5",
  "Name": "D"
}, {
  "Id": "6",
  "Name": "E"
}, {
  "Id": "7",
  "Name": "C"
}, {
  "Id": "8",
  "Name": "D"
}]

var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length ; i++ ){
  var obj = myArray[i];
  if(arr[obj.id] >= 0)
  {
    myArray.push(i);
    i--;
  }
  arr[obj.id] = i;
}
```

Comment: how it will return me Ids of duplicate names? This is something else i reckon.

Comment: console.log(arr)